# Push ant generated artifact to archiva repository through jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, ant, archiva

I am new to Jenkins and ant. I have a ant and maven project. The ant build file is used to generate custom jar file. I need to automate the process of uploading this jar file to Archiva repository. Please help.

Comment: I have already tried "Deploy Artifacts to maven repository" post build option but it only upload the pom.xml to archiva. It doesn't picks the ant generated jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Ant build files from Maven using the Maven-Antrun-Plugin. I had a similar problem and used the Maven-Antrun-Plugin to generate the jar and then the `deploy:deploy-file` goal to push it to Nexus. Archiva will probably work in the same way.